# How to debug Android system app with Maven in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, maven

I am creating some system app for android device. I am building the system app with maven and pushing it to `/system/app/` and verifying the app. But I am unable to debug the system app through eclipse because I am building it using maven and manually pushing. Is there any way to create system app through eclipse and debug the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Maven Integration for Eclipse](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html)

Comment: You might want to change the question title

Comment: thanks for ans, But even if I am able to build using eclipse maven plugin, I need to push the app to /system/app/ then I am not able to debug that app